# Changing the transport map changes the input for TLS policy map search

Tags: postfix

We are using a custom transport map because for certain domains we need to read the MX value from a TXT record and not use a standard MX lookup. We are using PostgreSQL for this, however the issue is present also when configured using the standard Berkeley DB.

With this command:
`/usr/sbin/postmap -q user@example.com pgsql:/etc/postfix/transport_map.cf` I get the following expected output:
`smtp:[mail.example.com]`

So far so good, but we also need to apply a `dane-only` TLS policy for the domain `example.com`.

For this I have an `smpt_tls_policy_maps` configured (also using PostgreSQL). However, I have seen that the search query is no longer trying to match on the domain `example.com` but it is trying to use the returned value from the transport map lookup `mail.example.com`.

This doesn´t work for us because we need to apply the TLS policy for domains and not the returned mail server.
It could feasibly happen that the target mail server `mail.example.com` is a mail server for multiple domains and the other domains are not configured with the TXT record from the transport map step which results in a "deferred" response because they do not have the necessary TLSA records to support the dane-only policy.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.